# Calculate month over month and year over year change for vintage data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe of economic series whose values can get revised every month, adding a new value for a given date and indexing it by `realtime_start` (see below dataframe). `realtime_start` indicates the date at which `value` for `date` becomes valid. This `value` expires as soon as another one takes its place.

| date | realtime_start | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-01 | 2020-12-04 | 142629.0 |
| 2020-11-01 | 2021-01-08 | 142764.0 |
| 2020-11-01 | 2021-02-05 | 142809.0 |
| 2020-12-01 | 2021-01-08 | 142624.0 |
| 2020-12-01 | 2021-02-05 | 142582.0 |
| 2020-12-01 | 2021-03-05 | 142503.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-05 | 142631.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-05 | 142669.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-02 | 142736.0 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-05 | 143048.0 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-04-02 | 143204.0 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-04-02 | 144120.0 |

I would like an easy way to calculate the month-over-month change in `value` based on the last known entry at `date`.

Calculation method: take the first release from month n (based on `realtime_start`) and subtract the relevant release from month n-1. Relevant release is the most recent release whose `realtime_start` date does not exceed that of month n.

See desired output below

| date | MoM change |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-01 | NaN |
| 2020-12-01 | -140 |
| 2021-01-01 | 49 |
| 2021-02-01 | 379 |
| 2021-03-01 | 916 |

For `2021-03-01`, the MoM change value is `144120.0 - 143204.0 = 916.0` 
For `2021-02-01`, the MoM change value is `143048.0 - 142669.0 = 379.0` 
For `2021-01-01`, the MoM change value is `142631.0 - 142582.0 = 49.0`

Similarly, I would like to calculate the year-over-year change based on the last known values at `date` (actual data frame extends further into the past). I would also like to calculate the 3-month (rolling) average of month-over-month change based on last known values at `date`.

[economic series dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGFBD.png)

Comment: looking like this is `fred` data? If yes,I think they provide MoM and YoY data change

Comment: It is. I don’t think they provide this via API, do they?

Comment: The calculation seems inconsistent.  For 2021-02-01, it uses the first entry (instead of last entry) of the month to deduct the last entry of the previous month, i.e. 2021-01-01.  For  2021-01-01, it uses the first entry to deduct the second last entry of the previous month.

Comment: You’re supposed to take the first release from month n and subtract the relevant release from month n-1. 

Relevant release is the most recent release whose release date does not exceed that of month n.

Comment: For 2020-12-01, should the relevant release be 12503 or 12583 ?  12503 seems the most recent release but you used the second most recent release 12583 for calculation of 2021-01-01

Comment: 12503 has a realtime_start date (2021-03-05) that exceeds that of the first release of following month (2021-02-05), which is why it is not used. I’m using the latest release whose release date comes before that of the next month’s entry.

Comment: Ok, please update your question to include this condition, which is an important condition / constraint for correct calculation.

Comment: @SeaBean just did - thanks

Comment: @ChristianAdib How do you calculate the value `245` corresponding to date `2020-11-01`?  because it seems not possible to calculate with the given sample.

Comment: You’re right — my bad. It is impossible to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

```
df = df.set_index('date')

first = df.groupby(level=0).first()
m = df['realtime_start'].le(first['realtime_start'].shift(-1))
last_val = df['value'].mask(~m).groupby(level=0).last().shift()

mom_change = (first['value'] - last_val).reset_index(name='MoM change')
```

#### Explanations

Set the `index` of the dataframe to the column `date` then `group` the dataframe on `level=0` and aggregate using `first` to select the first row for each unique `date`

```
>>> first
           realtime_start     value
date                               
2020-11-01     2020-12-04  142629.0
2020-12-01     2021-01-08  142624.0
2021-01-01     2021-02-05  142631.0
2021-02-01     2021-03-05  143048.0
2021-03-01     2021-04-02  144120.0
```

Shift the column `realtime_start`  in the `first` dataframe, then compare it with `realtime_start` column in `df` to create a boolean mask `m`

```
>>> m

date
2020-11-01     True
2020-11-01     True
2020-11-01    False
2020-12-01     True
2020-12-01     True
2020-12-01    False
2021-01-01     True
2021-01-01     True
2021-01-01    False
2021-02-01     True
2021-02-01     True
2021-03-01    False
Name: realtime_start, dtype: bool
```

Now mask the values in the `value` column using the above boolean mask then group this masked column on `level=0` and aggregate using last to select last row for each unique id

```
>>> last

date
2020-11-01         NaN
2020-12-01    142764.0
2021-01-01    142582.0
2021-02-01    142669.0
2021-03-01    143204.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Subtract the `value` column in `first` dataframe from the calculated `last_val` column to calculate the `MoM change`

```
>>> mom_change

        date  MoM change
0 2020-11-01         NaN
1 2020-12-01      -140.0
2 2021-01-01        49.0
3 2021-02-01       379.0
4 2021-03-01       916.0
```

PS: The dataframe must be sorted on `date` column in order for this solution to work properly

Comment: Thanks, Shubham! This is excellent -- exactly what I was looking for! How would you calculate the 3-month average MoM change? Again, the idea is to "sit" at date n and consider the data that is known to us then, calculate the month-over-month change over the past 3 months, and take an average of those values.

Comment: @ChristianAdib Not sure if i understand the question but I think we could group the dataframe `mom_change` on the frequency of `3 months` and aggregate column `value` using `mean` to get the average `MoM Change` for the past three months.

Comment: It won't work as expected. Let me give you a quick example to clarify:

To calculate the 3M average MoM change for `2021-03-01`, here is what we have ot do: `1/3 * [(144120.0 - 143204.0) + (143204.0 - 142736.0) + (142736.0 - 142503.0
)] = 1/3 *(144120.0 - 142503.0) = 539 `

Comment: Please check `3m_change = 1/3*(first['value'] - last_val).reset_index(name='3M change')`

Comment: @ChristianAdib Welcome to Stackoverflow. If this answered your question then you may consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)